# Contact Form Fields not being sent

Tags: php, forms, contacts

The project and phone fields in my contact form script arent working. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong as every other field works great:

```
<? php
include('contact-config.php');
$contact_form_version = strtolower($contact_form_version);
if (empty($to) || empty($contact_form_version) || ($contact_form_version != 'php' && $contact_form_version != 'html')) {
die('Error: The contact form has not been setup correctly.');
} else {
if ($contact_form_version == 'php') {
    $formLocation = 'contact.php';
} else if ($contact_form_version == 'html') {
    $formLocation = 'contact.html';
}
}
if (!empty($_POST['isAjax']) && $_POST['isAjax'] == '1') {
$ajax = true;
} else {
$ajax = false;
}
if (empty($_POST['name']) || empty($_POST['project']) || empty($_POST['email']) ||  empty($_POST['phone']) || empty($_POST['message'])) {
if ($ajax || $contact_form_version == 'html') {
    die('Error: Missing variables');
} else {
    header("Location: $formLocation?msg=missing-variables");
    exit;
}
}
if (!preg_match("/^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\@([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\.([A-Za-z]{2,8})$/", $_POST['email'])) {
if ($ajax || $contact_form_version == 'html') {
    die('Error: Invalid email address');
} else {
    header("Location: $formLocation?msg=invalid-email-address");
    exit;
}
}
$name = $_POST['name'];
$project = $_POST['project'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$code = $_POST['captcha'];
$eip = $_POST['eip'];
$to = $to;
$headers = 'From: '.$name.' <'.$email.'>'." \r\n";
$headers. = 'Reply-To: '.$email."\r\n";
if (isset($cc) && $cc != '') {
$headers. = 'Cc: '.$cc."\r\n";
}
if (isset($bcc) && $bcc != '') {
$headers. = 'Bcc: '.$bcc."\r\n";
}
$headers. = 'X-Mailer: PHP/'.phpversion();
$subject = 'Contact Form Enquiry';
$message = wordwrap($message, 70);
if (mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
if ($ajax || $contact_form_version == 'html') {
    die('Mail sent');
} else {
    header("Location: $formLocation?msg=mail-sent");
    exit;
}
} else {
if ($ajax || $contact_form_version == 'html') {
    die('Error: Mail failed');
} else {
    header("Location: $formLocation?msg=mail-failed");
    exit;
}
} ?>
```

Any help with this would be hugely appreciated guys.

Thanks a bunch

Comment: You're creating `$project` and `$phone` variables, but not doing anything with them

Comment: I pay for white space too :/

Comment: FYI your code is a mess, new lines and indentation will make code much easier to work with

Comment: @andrewsi You have point there ;-)

Comment: One method is to use a `foreach...as` that will capture each `$_POST` --- will avoid a lot of assignments.

Comment: 1) OP posts 2) Answers/comments come in 3) OP disappears into thin air; *"classic"*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your not actually sending the details try.

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$project = $_POST['project'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$code = $_POST['captcha'];
$eip = $_POST['eip'];

$content = $name . ' ' . $project . ' ' . $email . ' ' . $phone . ' ' . $message . ' ' . $code . ' ' . $eip;

if (mail($to, $subject, $content, $headers)) {
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem today , I fixed by changing this :

```
else {
    header("Location: $formLocation?msg=missing-variables");
    exit;
}
```

To

```
 else {
    header("Location: thank-you.html"); 
    exit;
}
```

NB: I created a file and called thank-you .

My bad! I had problem with redirection ..